# Angular not auto completing email?

Tags: angular

Hello I have an input field for email like this:

```
 <input class="generic-input" #emailInput autocomplete="new-email" type="text" formControlName="email"
        (blur)="trimSpace()" (keypress)="disallowSpace($event)"
        name="email">
```

however i am not getting autocompletion like from usually HTML5 functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a typo in autocomplete attribute.

```
autocomplete="new-email"
```

It should be `autocomplete="email"` instead.

P.S. `new-password` is valid option, not `new-email`.

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete` attribute doesn't have `new-email` value. You should use just `email` instead. So your code will look like this:

```
 <input class="generic-input" #emailInput autocomplete="email" type="text" formControlName="email"
        (blur)="trimSpace()" (keypress)="disallowSpace($event)"
        name="email">
```